# AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute – call base class method through multiple layers of inheritance

Tags: python, oop

How is it possible to call a "Base-classes'" method when going through multiple layers of inheritance in Python?

E.g.

```py
class A():
    def do_something(self):
        print('Class A')

class B(A):
    def do_something(self):
        super().do_something()
        print('Class B')

class C(B):
    def do_something(self):
        super().do_something()
        print('Class C')

class D(C):
    def do_something(self):
        super(A, self).do_something()
        print('Class D')
```

Results in:

```sh
>>> A().do_something()
Class A
>>> C().do_something()
Class A
Class B
Class C
>>> D().do_something()
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'do_something'
```

The desired behavior would result in:

```sh
>>> D().do_something()
Class A
class D
```

I tried using `A(self).do_something()` in `class D`, but whenever an `__init__` is specified, this will fail with `TypeError: __init__() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'arg1', 'arg2', and 'arg3'`

This question has been asked quite a lot on StackOverflow, but none seem to provide an answer to the specific problem, trying to delegate the call to the Base-class' function. I'm a bit confused since I think this `super(<target_class>, self)...` behavior works in Django models.

Comment: ``super(A, self).do_something()`` calls ``do_something`` on the superclass *of ``A``* – which is object. You can call ``A.do_something(self)`` if you really have to run a specific method – but you should not have to.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I didn't seem to remember correctly – thought I already tried that. But this works as expected. Thanks. – What do you mean – *but you should not have to*?

Comment: Inheritance is usually considered transparent for classes. For example, ``B`` can expect to inherit from *some* ``A`` (because of ``B(A)``) but not *specifically* ``A`` (because of multiple inheritance). That's basically why we have ``super()`` instead of accessing the "super class" directly. If a class explicitly accesses a *specific* parent class, this transparency is broken; intermediate classes can no longer expect that inheritance/mro is respected. This basically breaks *all* consistency guarantees between methods.

Comment: As an example, consider that ``B`` relies on ``do_something`` having some auxiliary effect (say, counting calls) because it has another method ``B.reset_something`` requiring that effect (e.g. undoing each call). Since ``D`` *is a* ``B`` but skips ``B.do_something``, the invariant between ``B.do_something`` and ``B.reset_something`` is broken even though ``D`` *is a* ``B`` for which this invariant should hold. Now, *in practice* if you know all invariants then you can work around them so things don't blow up – but at that point it's your job to manually maintain the *entire* inheritance chain.